# Подскажите почему applicationContext.xml не работает? Иконка в проекте красная (xml)

Tags: spring, maven

`[![screenshot][1]][1]`

````
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="testBean"
          class="est.TestBean">
        <constructor-arg value="ABED"/>
    </bean>

</beans> ```


 ```screenshot==>``` [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvWzE.jpg
````

Comment: Пытаюсь просто создать бин и потом извлечь его из ApplicationContext-a

Comment: какая ошибка падает?

Comment: Ошибки никакой вроде все работает но обычно в проектах эти файлы меняют иконку когда в них вставляешь код

Comment: вопрос был про то, что у тебя что-то ***не работает***